# Exact Differential 1-form on $ R^{3}$

Tags: differential-forms

[Check this link for the question:  total differential means exact in this case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcZFG.jpg)

The question want to show $ I\eta$ is not exact ($I\eta \neq dq$, where d is exterior derivative and q is 0-form). I am failing to prove that $I\eta$ is not  $C^{1},C^{2},C^{3}$ otherwise $I\eta$ is exact. Any help would greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand your approach: If $I\in\mathcal C^\infty(\mathbb R^3)$, then $I\eta$ is a well-defined smooth differential form. I think the way to go is just to prove that $\mathrm d(I\eta)\neq0$

Comment: I am trying prove there is no such function $I(x,y,x)$ which will make $I\eta$ is exact. I am proving it by contradiction, Assume $I\eta$ is exact then it must be $C^{1} or \ C^{2} or \ C^{3}$.

Comment: You are on a confused track. You've already been told that $I\eta$ will be $C^\infty$ for any smooth function. The issue is that for *no* choice of function $I$ will the $1$-form $I\eta$ be exact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SKETCH**: I will switch to the letter $f$ for the function. Suppose $f\eta$ is exact. If so, then it must be closed, so
$$d(f\eta) = df\wedge\eta + f\,d\eta = 0.$$
This implies that
$$d\eta\wedge\eta = 0.$$
(Why?) Does this equation hold?

Comment: I see, if $f\eta$ is exact then $ d(f\eta) \wedge \eta$ = $fd\eta\wedge \eta$=0 since f is non-zero then $d\eta\wedge\eta = 0$. doing the calculations, $d\eta\wedge\eta \neq 0$. So, $d(f\eta)$ is not closed. Then it is not exact.

Comment: There you go. Make sense now? (This is a useful criterion for whether an integrating factor exists, by the way.)

Comment: yep, thank you.